# Hover and selectors

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am completely new to Javascript / Jquery and I have a problem.

Suppose in my html page I have a number (undefined) of class to hover (when I hover something happens). Here I put 2 examples.

```
<div class='hover' id='hov33749'>Wikipedia</div>
<div class='hover' id='hov32747'>Google</div>
```

How to :

1. Apply a function when I hover on Google or Wikipedia
2. Retrieve the div corresponding to the hover (id, text, position on the page etc.)

I tried to put a random id and put some regex but it doesn't work well

I thank you in advance

Comment: Not clear what you wants to do

Comment: If i hover on Google or Wikipedia in a web page, I want to apply a certain function which needs the position of the div in the page, and the text inside the div. I can have 100 hover class in the same web page with 100 different texts

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting out with JavaScript, I'd suggest refrain JQuery for now and understand how the language itself works.

The following code adds an `eventListener` to all elements with class `hover`, the functionality of which is in `onHover` method

```js
const onHover = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.id;
  const text = e.target.textContent;
    console.log(id, text);
}

const hover = document.querySelectorAll(".hover");
hover.forEach(item => item.addEventListener("mouseover", onHover));
```

```html
<div class='hover' id='hov33749'>Wikipedia</div>
<div class='hover' id='hov32747'>Google</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [JQuery documentation
.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```js
$(".hover").each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        // Do something ...
        console.log("Text: " + $(this).text() + ", Id: " + $(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Comment: No reason to use `.each()` just do `$(".hover").hover`

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't recommend to use jQuery to someone who is completely new in this world. I would use plain JavaScript.